# Nexus 7 stuck on Google screen Ubuntu Touch

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 7 with [these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install). After the tablet rebooted, it got stuck on the Google screen. The article says `If the deploy fails (example: boots to black screen), try wiping the`/data`partition on your device and redeploy.` I used ClockworkMod Recovery to wipe /data. When I ran `phablet-flash ubuntu-system --channel devel --no-backup` it said I didn't have the permissions to do this. I went into cwm and hit "fix permissions" and it did the same thing. When I run `adb devices` it returns: `List of devices attached ???????????? no permissions`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my permissions by killing adb server using the command

```
sudo adb kill-server
```

and restarting it

```
sudo adb start-server
```

Then My tablet shows up with `sudo adb devices`.

I found this on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460656/android-debug-bridge-adb-device-no-permissions